# Black lines around/on my object

Tags: 3d-view, edit-mode

I'm following Blender Guru's tutorial on his donut, and for some reason I can't get my donut to go back to it's original colour (the light grey colour). I'm stuck in edit mode but not really edit mode, because I can't edit, but it has the black squared lines like in edit mode. I appreciate any help as I've just started and have no idea.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. press `z` and choose Solid Mode